# How to scroll the scrollable content loaded in the webview which is one item of the RecycleView

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview, android-webview, touch-event

Having a RecycleView, it has a few items and one of them is a view contains a WebView. Inside the WebView it loads an html and there is a iframe which has an html table content and it is vertically scrollable (the containing div has fix height smaller than the the table's height).

Seems there is issue with the RecyclerView that it does not pass the touch event to the WebView.

This what happenS:

When touch the screen to drag, the recycleView's onInterceptTouchEvent() first `return false at ACTION_DOWN` and then `return true when the event is  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. This `return true` will send to the target child view a MotionEvent.Cancel, and all further
events will be delivered to RecycleView's onTouchEvent()

```
TestDerivedRecycleView:onInterceptTouchEvent(), return: false     
              event: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0... }, this.scrollState: 0

TestDerivedRecycleView:onInterceptTouchEvent(), return: true
              event: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0... }, this.scrollState: 1
```

So I created a derived RecycleView, that when the event is ACTION_MOVE on the target view is the WebView then `return false to let WebView handle the drag/move`.

It is partially working.  Since the webView may have some other content such as text area. If touched on that textarea it is not scrollable so the recycle view will not scroll.  Only if touch and drag that table element the table element will scroll the table content.

The desired behavior should be when drag any item on the RecyclerView the RecyclerView should scroll it items up,  only when drag on that scrollable table element the table should scroll it's content if the bottom of the table is not displayed.

How to make the webview's content scroll working when it is a child item of the RecycleView?

```
class TestDerivedRecycleView : RecyclerView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        val ret = super.onTouchEvent(event)

        Log.d("+++", "+++ TestDerivedRecycleView:onTouchEvent(), ret: $ret" +
                "\nevent.action: ${event.action}, " +
                "\nevent: $event" +
                "\nthis: ${this}")

       return ret   
    }


    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        val ret = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)

        val myCell = findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)

        Log.w("+++", "+++ TestDerivedRecycleView:onInterceptTouchEvent(), ret: $ret" +
                "\nmyCell: $myCell"+
                "\n event.action: ${event.action}, this.scrollState: ${this.scrollState}" +
                "\nevent: $event"+
                "\nthis: $this")

        // when the event is ACTION_MOVE and is touched on the WebView then return false to let WebView handle the event
        if (
                (myCell is ArticleWebView) &&
                event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                && this.scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
        ) { 

            Log.e("+++", "+++ TestDerivedRecycleView:onInterceptTouchEvent(), (myCell is WebView) return false")

            return false
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and solved with this -
In your `WebView` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   
     requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    if(scrollY==0){
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }else{
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

find a solution, not idea though.

basically,  the issue is RecycleView intercepts the 'move' event (its `super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)` will return true) so that the Webview will receive a 'cancel' event and no other subsequent events, which make the items in the RecyclerView scroll but webview does not get chance to scroll its content.

the solution is to not allow the RecyclerView intercept the 'move' event.

There is other problem is with this approach, since in the WebView the html could have some content is scrollable and some is not scrollable.  If simple let webview take over the move and the touch point is  on some non-scrollable area then the touch/drag move will not have effect (item item in the RecyclerView will not scroll as well, since it did not intercept the event anymore).

So this partial fix is to only when two fingers are touched on webview then disable the RecyclerView's intercept. This way at least single finger touch will continue to scroll the list item, and two fingers touch will scroll the webview's scrollable content.

Bad part is still that two fingers touch one webview's non scrollable area will have no scroll effect.

If anyone knows better solution, please share, thanks!

in Webview added the listener:

```
val listener = OnTouchListener { v, event ->
    var perantViewGroup = v.parent
    when {
        event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mFingersDown = 1
        event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> mFingersDown++
        event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> mFingersDown--
        event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> mFingersDown = 0
    }

    if ((mFingersDown >= 2) && event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        perantViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    } else if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        perantViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
    }

    false
}
webview.setOnTouchListener(listener)
```

and also in the RecycleView adding some help to prevent it from intercept the ‘move’ event.

```
class TestDerivedRecycleView : RecyclerView {
    ......

    private var mFingersDown = 0
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        when {
            event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mFingersDown = 1
            event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> mFingersDown++
            event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> mFingersDown--
            event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> mFingersDown = 0
        }
        val touchedCell = findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)
        if ((touchedCell is WebView) && (mFingersDown >= 2) && event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return false
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```